# Configure all services Windows

Tags: windows, services

Is there any way to manage all the services in Windows, without having to configure them one by one? Something like a wildcard for the sc command.

Comment: How about a loop through a list of service names in a txt file

Comment: I luv disabling things that are unnessisary for my purposes, but I can guarentee that disabling the whole rack via a wildcard will make things worse than leaving them be. There are a few that seem easy to shut off that will cause a lot of trouble.  (disabling the event log for example).  Some very odd dependencies in windows 7 too.  Using AutoRuns is a good way , and saving the changes in autoruns with Numbered saves (Ar01, Ar02 etc), so you can retract and compare.  Note: autoruns only disables.  Services are so totally dependant on the computers use and configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Powershell.

```
Get-Service * | Where {$_.Status -eq "Stopped" -and $_.Name -eq "TabletInputService"} | Start-Service
```

This one would start the service you want (instead of "TabletInputService").

```
Get-Service * | Where {$_.Status -eq "Running" -and $_.Name -eq "TabletInputService"} | Stop-Service
```

This one would stop the service you want (instead of "TabletInputService").

But the big question here is what are you parameters exactly? How do you choose which services to stop? As Psycogeek said, it's a bad idea to stop all services, since there are many that are crucial for the system to function at all.

If you intend to disable a specific list of services you hand-picked, than you'd have to write it at least once in the script...

Comment: `Get-Service`'s `-Name` actually takes wildcards and exclusion lists, as does its `-DisplayName`.